# Is there an easy way to use the lag function for many iterations on the same column?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, lag, impala

I am working with Impala (but could do the same in oracle Sql) and I  have a column for which I need to fill in the nulls with the previous non null value for every merchandise (even if it is 25 rows before).

I wrote a query that could get me to my end result but I will need to write 30 case when statements (as many as the days of a month). 
Is there an easier way to do it?

I used the lag function with but could only make it work by getting the previous value of the column. If that value is null, I have to redo the lag function on the new column I had just created

```
select a.*, 
case when new_value  is null then LAG (new_value,1) OVER ( partition by merchandise ORDER BY date_mec) else new_value end as new_value_2 
from
(SELECT merchandise, date_mec, value,
case when value is null then LAG (value,1) OVER ( partition by merchandise ORDER BY date_mec) else value end AS new_value 
FROM mer_try_value) a
```

My table looks like this

[image]

The table that I created with 2 case when statements looks like this

[image]

Is there a better way to reach to my required end result?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you don't want previous value if current row has non-null value. So use `last_value` with `ignore nulls` clause:

```
select merchandise, date_mec, value,
       last_value(value) ignore nulls over (partition by merchandise order by date_mec) new_val
  from mer_try_value
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0ec6668d0fd0ddf90fe612ac5bd0f265)</sup>**

`Last_value()` by default checks current row and if it's null looks for last non-null value.

Comment: If this answer resolved your question then accept it so that it will be marked as resolved.